# Recaptcha 2 (a.k.a. nocaptcha) doesn't load on Internet Explorer 8 on first load

Tags: python, internet-explorer-8, recaptcha

I am using new recaptcha2 and everything seems to work flawlessly on all modern browsers, however I have a problem only with IE8.

Captcha load properly on second and next visit on the page, but never on first load or in Private Mode.

What is even more strange, [google recaptcha 2 page demo](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) doesn't have this problems. I am using [django-nocaptcha-recaptcha](https://github.com/ImaginaryLandscape/django-nocaptcha-recaptcha) package, which is based on [recaptcha-client](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/) for python, so I believe my configuration is pretty standard.

Console doesn't show any errors. Divs are not populate by recaptcha code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google on [their recaptcha2 developers guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?hl=pl) suggest to use a snipet like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

django-nocaptcha-recaptcha use similar [piece of code](https://github.com/ImaginaryLandscape/django-nocaptcha-recaptcha/blob/master/demo/demo/templates/index.html) and also use a line like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

This suppose to cause a problem, since `ascync` and `defer` are supported in IE 10+. In my case, when I used:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Problem disappeared :)

Comment: Very useful, I was experiencing the same issue :)